# Firebase - populate property/array with additional data

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

The below observable creates an array of event objects.

```
eventsRef: AngularFireList<any>;
events: Observable<any>;

this.eventsRef = db.list('events');

this.events = this.eventsRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {

return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
});
```

I need to add additional data to `this.events` from other database lists. So I need each event object to contain a guest count and data `eventsFilters`. I'm not sure how to do that. This is what I have so far:

```
this.events = this.eventsRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {

  changes.map(data => {
    console.log(data.payload.key)
    this.db.object(`/eventsFilters/${data.payload.key}`)
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data) //event filters
      })
  })

  changes.map(data => {
    console.log(data.payload.key)
    this.db.object(`/eventsGuests/${data.payload.key}`)
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(data => {
        let guestCount = Object.keys(data).length;
        console.log(guestCount)
        this.guestCount = guestCount; //guest count
      })
  })
  return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
});
```

Edit --------

I got this far using `combineLatest` but I'm still not sure how to group each event data.

```
this.eventsRef.snapshotChanges()
  .switchMap(
    (changes) => {
      let userQueries: Observable<any>[] = [];
      let lists: Array<string> = ['eventsFilters', 'eventsGuests'];

      changes.map(data => {
        for (let list of lists) {
          userQueries.push(this.db.object(`/${list}/${data.payload.key}`).valueChanges());
        }
      })

      userQueries.push(this.eventsRef.snapshotChanges());

      return Observable.combineLatest(userQueries);
    })
  .subscribe((d) => {
    console.log(d)
  });
```

`console.log(d)` outputs something like this:

```
[
   {}, //object with data from eventsFilters for first event
   {}, //object with data from eventsGuests for first event
   {}, //object with data from eventsFilters for second event
   {}, //object with data from eventsGuests for second event
   ... 
   [{},{} ...] //array with all events
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example combining 3 observable:

```
combinedData$ = combineLatest( entityList$, settings$, currentUser$).pipe(
  map(([entityList, pageSetting, currentUser]) => {
    //entityList, pageSettingand currentUser holds the last value emitted on each observables.

    if (!pageSetting.ShowAllOrganisation) {
      //If not showing all organisation, then we have to filter it
      retVal = entityList.filter(entity=> entity.organisationId === currentUser.organisationId);
    }

    return retVal;
  })
);
```

CombineLatest will return a new observable. If one of the 3 observable emmits a new value, the combineLatest will be triggered and emmits a new value. For more info on how combineLatest is working visit the [official documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-combineLatest)